# How to get Termset using the new SharePoint framework SPFx

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling

I am new to to Typescript, watched videos and created the sample application of client webpart using new SharePoint development framework. All sample application worked well, and using Rest Queries i was able to do some of the List operation.but now my current Project Requirement, to get the termsets values from Taxonomy and as i aware there is no Rest end points available for Termset yet.(let me know if its available.)

I followed https://github.com/gandjustas/sptypescript , for some sample to help for my requirement but with no luck yet.

followed this blog http://thecollaborationcorner.com/2016/08/31/part-4-the-navigation-implementation/#.WD622YVOKM8 . even this is specific to Navigation Termset.

Could anybody help on this, how i can get the Taxonomy termset values using new SharePoint framework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a sample for **Taxonomy** in [sp-dev-fx-webparts](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/dev/samples/knockout-taxonomy). Following things you can get from this sample

- Reading taxonomy term stores' hierarchy from SharePoint
- Loading JavaScript Object Model scripts
- creating Knockout components

I believe you can get help from [this](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/blob/dev/samples/knockout-taxonomy/src/webparts/termSetRequester/data-helpers/DataHelperSP.ts) file to get term **Termset**.

Comment: This is giving me error, and not working on IE,anyone faced the same issue?

Answer (score 2):

You can use @pnp/sp-taxonomy/terms.

Install with:

```ps1
npm install @pnp/logging @pnp/common @pnp/odata @pnp/sp @pnp/sp-taxonomy @pnp/sp-clientsvc -- save
```

Import:

```ts
import { Session } from '@pnp/sp-taxonomy';
```

Usage:

```ts
const taxonomy = new Session(siteCollectionURL);
const store: any = taxonomy.termStores.getByName(termStoreName);
store.getTermSetById(termsetId).terms.select('Name', 'Id', 'Parent').get()
.then((data: any[]) => {
  console.log(data)
})
```

Docs: https://github.com/pnp/pnpjs/blob/dev/packages/sp-taxonomy/docs/terms.md

Comment: This is not working in IE